# Como colocar link (href) em linha de <table>

Tags: php, mysql, microsoft-azure

Eai galera beleza?

Eu tenho um código em PHP puxando dados de um Azure Mysql e com esses dados estou criando uma tabela, eu queria que cada linha da tabela fosse um link, que quando eu clicar abrir outra página com o ticket completo, parecido com o que o gmail faz.

```
 <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th class= "nome">Nome</th>
            <th>Número do Onibus</th>
            <th class= "telefone">Telefone</th>
            <th>Tipo de ocorrência</th>
            <th class= "data">Data da Ocorrência</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php 
            while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>".$user_data['idocorrencia']."</td>";
              echo "<td class='nome'>".$user_data['nome']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$user_data['num_onibus']."</td>";
              echo "<td class='telefone'>".$user_data['telefone']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$user_data['tipo']."</td>";
              echo "<td class='data'>".$user_data['dt_ocorrencia']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$user_data['descricao']."</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
            }
          ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para transformar cada linha da tabela em um link que redirecione para outra página com o ticket completo, você pode adicionar um link ao redor de cada linha e passar o ID da ocorrência como um parâmetro na URL. Para fazer isso, você pode adicionar um link ao redor da primeira célula de cada linha (a célula que contém o ID da ocorrência), usando a tag  do HTML. O link terá como destino a outra página, que será criada para exibir o ticket completo, e incluirá o ID da ocorrência como um parâmetro na URL.

Aqui está um exemplo de como fazer isso, utilizando o código PHP que você forneceu:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th class= "nome">Nome</th>
      <th>Número do Ônibus</th>
      <th class= "telefone">Telefone</th>
      <th>Tipo de Ocorrência</th>
      <th class= "data">Data da Ocorrência</th>
      <th>Descrição</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php 
    while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $ticket_id = $user_data['idocorrencia'];//Pegando o ID da ocorrencia
      $link = "ticket.php?id=".$ticket_id;//Gerando o link
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td><a href='$link'>".$ticket_id."</a></td>";//Link para página de ticket
      echo "<td class='nome'>".$user_data['nome']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$user_data['num_onibus']."</td>";
      echo "<td class='telefone'>".$user_data['telefone']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$user_data['tipo']."</td>";
      echo "<td class='data'>".$user_data['dt_ocorrencia']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$user_data['descricao']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Observe que, no exemplo acima, estamos criando uma variável `$link` que contém o endereço da página *ticket.php* com o ID da ocorrência passado como um parâmetro na URL. Depois, envolvemos o valor da primeira célula de cada linha em um link usando a tag , onde o valor do atributo href é o valor da variável `$link`.

Isso cria um link clicável que levará o usuário para a página *ticket.php* com o ID da ocorrência sendo passado como um parâmetro na URL. Na página *ticket.php*, você pode usar o ID da ocorrência para buscar as informações do ticket completo no banco de dados e exibi-las para o usuário.

Comment: mano muito obrigado, funcionou o link, agora só estou vendo como pegar o ID do link (sou bem iniciante mesmo kkk), mas o link direcionou para a outro arquivo

Comment: Consegui fazer o get do link funcionou, muito obrigado mano

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!